# Pre-compiled "minimal perfect hash" for hundreds of strings in C

Tags: c, hash, hashmap, c-preprocessor, hashtable

I am working on an embedded system where I have a lot of room for my application (i.e. the code and text segments have no limitations), but I'm not allowed to use up much RAM (i.e. keep the number of threads to a bare minimum, limit stack sizes, dynamic memory allocation is avoided unless absolutely necessary). We also have a vendor-supplied GCC compiler that does some extra "magic under the hood" for us, whatever that means (can't share details, under NDA).

In my application, I have to provide a search function for thousands of strings between 8 and 63 ASCII characters in length, and the strings are auto-generated from a python script that is provided to me. **This script can change without notice, adding/removing entries, prefixing all of them, etc, so the input data effectively changes between builds of my application.** I originally planned to build a simple run-time hash map via the `hcreate()` function, or writing my own hash table, but it would use more RAM than my program is allotted.

Is there a way, to create a "minimal perfect hash" function, that is easy to implement in say, C, as well as via python and/or BASH command-line utilities (i.e. GNU coreutils), **without requiring my C application to link against anything other than `libc.so`**? I'm trying to create a hashmap that:

- Has a minimal key width (i.e. 16 bits).
- Has no collisions.
- Can be pre-computed using shell and/or python scripts to pre-generate a Cheader file with string-literal and integer hash mappings.
- Can be searched at run time in a simple C application, where the run-time search function only computes hashes and searches the pre-computed hash-table provided by my auto-generated header.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/gperf/ is what you're looking for.

Comment: Maybe you want to generate [radix tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_tree)?

Comment: `(can't share details, under NDA).` That sounds like a **GPL violation**. The (modified) source should be publicly released.

Comment: Here some hash functions http://www.burtleburtle.net/bob/hash/doobs.html

Comment: gperf should work. If the number of keys is too large, you could use my [minperf](https://github.com/thomasmueller/minperf) tool, but it's mainly written in Java - there is a C version included however. It's still work-in-progress however.